# Formatting using vim

Tags: vim, vi

I have a file with 100s of lines of data with the following format:

```
    Smith, John@email.com, 271Ave 
    Doe, James@email.com, 270Ave  
    .
    .
```

and so on

I would like to change the all the entires into the following format:

```
     {"name": "Smith", "email": "John@email.com", "Address:" "271Ave"}
```

Please suggest as to how this can be achieved in vim.

Comment: Why do you want to use `vim`?

Comment: Perhaps you need sed or awk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing it with vim is easy, if each line has same text format. Open the file in vim, assume your cursor at line1, then record macro in register `q`:

```
qqI{"name": "<esc>f,i"<esc>wi"email": "<esc>;i"<esc>wi"Address:" "<esc>A"}<esc>+q
```

then replay the macro 200 times (you can give 999, if you have more than 200 lines)

```
200@q
```

you will get the desired output. You can also use nesting macro so that you don't have to type the `200`.

Answer (score 1):

@Kent has answered the question.

Here is how it can be done using `awk` if anybody like to do with awk:

```
awk -F, 'function ltrim(s) { sub(/^[ \t\r\n]+/, "", s); return s } function rtrim(s) { sub(/[ \t\r\n]+$/, "", s); return s } {print "{\"name\": \""$1"\", \"email\": \""ltrim($2)"\", \"Address\": \""rtrim(ltrim($3))"\"}"}' < tmp
```

easy to read:

```
awk -F, '
function ltrim(s) { sub(/^[ \t\r\n]+/, "", s); return s }
function rtrim(s) { sub(/[ \t\r\n]+$/, "", s); return s }
{
print "{\"name\": \""$1"\", \"email\": \""ltrim($2)"\", \"Address\": \""rtrim(ltrim($3))"\"}"
}
' < tmp
```

copy paste the command and replace `tmp` with your file name.

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
:%s/\([^, ]\+\), \([^, ]\+\), \([^, ]\+\)/{"name": "\1", "email": "\2", "Address
": "\3"}
```

`\([^, ]\+\)` groups any characters that not includes `,` or space  .